# Alternative for 'in' operator for nested lists

Tags: python, nested-lists, in-operator

If I want to find something in a list in python I can use the 'in' operator:

```
list = ['foo', 'bar']
'foo' in list #returns True
```

But what should I do if I want to find something in a nested list?

```
list = [('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'foo')]
'foo' in list #returns False
```

Is it possible to do it in one row without a for loop for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually that's a nested tuple, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want `any`:

```
>>> list = [('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'foo')]
>>> any('foo' in e for e in list)
True
```

Some sort of loop is inevitable though.

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you :) I did not know that I can connect these statemens + operators in one line. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's abusive, but you can do this in one line pretty easily.

```
mainlist = [('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'foo')]
[elem for elem in sublist for sublist in mainlist] #['bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']

'foo' in [elem for elem in sublist for sublist in mainlist] # True
```

Comment: And this is your method Good!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with `in`

```
>>> list = [('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'foo')]
>>> 'foo' in (x[1] for x in list)
True
```

**EDIT**: this method check only if `foo` is as fist element.

To search as 'foo' a element (any):

```
 >>>'foo' in reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, list)   
 True
```

Some more try:

```
In [7]: list
Out[7]: [('foo', 'me', 'bar'), ('bar', 'foo', 'you')]
In [8]: 'me' in reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, list)
Out[8]: True

In [9]: 'you' in reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, list)
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. `[x[1] for x in list]` just searches the second element of every internal tuple, ie `['bar', 'foo']`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use itertools.chain like that :

```
from itertools import chain

nested__seq = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]

print 4 in chain(*nested__seq)
```

PS : you shouldn't override bultins like "list"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of iterables with arbitrary depth, flatten it first:

```
import collections 

li= [('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'foo'),[[('deeper',('foobar'))]]]

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

print 'deeper' in flatten(li)  
print 'foo' in flatten(li) 
print 'nope' in flatten(li)
```

Prints:

```
True
True
False
```